# Image processing - Music note blocks detection

Tags: image-processing

I have a music note sheet (like this for example)
[image: Music note]

, I want to detect the position of each block in it and then detect the vertical lines that split it, To be like this.

[image: music note splitted]

Can you help me how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect lines in the image. For horizontal ones this should give you five at a time which are the staves and vertical ones may need a bit more processing to figure out what are stems and what are bar lines.

Comment: Thanks, I used Hough transform in Aforge library, and my problem now is in the vertical ones. because Hough transform get the r & Theta, but I can't get the start and end point of each line.

Comment: You can search along the line for the actual start and end points.